# newInstance() on abstract classes?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, abstract-class

I have an abstract Fragment class (call it A) and a Fragment class that extends it (call it B). I currently invoke `newInstance` when making objects of class B, but I am wondering how I can also do something similar for class A, because there are default arguments I'd like to save for class A (by storing values in an argument Bundle). But since abstract classes cannot be instantiated, I am unsure how to go about saving such defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Do this declare an object foo as reference to A, so you can use ALL the elements in the abstract class, then if any B feature is required, you cast it to B, which is valid since B extends A

```
A foo = new B()
foo.aMethodFromA();
((B)foo).aMethodFromB();
```